# How to apply validation on p-table in cell edit text box?

Tags: angular, primeng

How to apply validation on p-table in cell edit text box?

Below is the link for the same.

[primeng table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Inputs are in your control. You can give anything you want.

Comment: yes input is in my control but how i will apply reactive form validation when user click on particular cell ?